# MySQL - Combining three columns into one with specific formatting

Tags: mysql, formatting

In my MySQL DB table I have a column called StartDate (of varchar type) plus three separate integer columns; Day, Month, Year.

What I want to do is combine the Day, Month and Year values and insert the resulting value into the StartDate field in the format dd/mm/yy (e.g. `03/07/84`).

This wouldn't be too difficult but a lot of the Day and Month values are only one digit long, so those need to be prefixed with a 0 (e.g. 1 becomes 01, 9 becomes 09, 11 remains unaltered) in order to meet the required StartDate formatting.

The other problem is the Year field. This currently holds a 4 digit year, so the first 2 digits need to be deleted to meet the StartDate formatting (e.g. 1984 becomes 84, 2001 becomes 01).

Can anyone help work out the procedure I need to go through to achieve this.
I'm guessing I need to work on the Day, Month and Year columns first to get them in the right formatting before then copying them and adding the '/' characters into the StartDate column.

Thanks a lot in advance for all help and assistance.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Having data in two places is a bad idea. Better to write a function in your application code that turns the data you have into the right format as it comes out. Also, why not use the MySQL DATE format?

Comment: @MattGibson I agree that having data in two places is bad, that's why I'm creating the StartDate from the Day, Month and Year columns, then I'll delete those to leave StartDate. I'm not using the MySQL DATE format because of the way the StartDate field's contents will be used on the front end of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE `my_super_datestable` SET startdate = 
    date_format(str_to_date(concat_ws(
                          '/', `day`, `month`, `year`), '%e/%c/%Y'), '%d/%m/%y');
```

Comment: That's brilliant. It's perfectly achieved what I was trying to do - and saved me a lot of typing! Many thanks @mantigatos.